# How to do this loop in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, loops, twig

I'm learning twig language! I have a question.
How can I do this loop en twig? I want to concat, in a string var, all the names of my list.

```
{% for student in studentList %}
    {% set studentString ~ student.name %} // How can i do this line?
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% set studentString = '' %}
{% for student in studentList %}
    {% studentString = studentString ~ student.name %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You probably want to add some separators between names